# change uiimageview background colors in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

[![the result screenshot--][https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRAJ.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRAJ.png)
and I want change that like behind
[![enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBMsJ.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBMsJ.png)
When slide bar opens, I want to make background behind slide bar darker covering UIimageview, but background are getting darker except UIimageView. Is there any way to get darker including images?

```
   //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  SideBarMenu
    //
    //  Created by Alexandre on 30/01/2015.
    //  Copyright (c) 2015 Alexandre. All rights reserved.
    //

import UIKit
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var hedgeImage: UIImageView!

    func sideBarWillOpen() {
       /* let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 200, backgroundView.frame.size.height)
        backgroundView.addSubview(blurView)*/

        backgroundView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.grayColor()
        hedgeImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    func sideBarWillClose() {
        backgroundView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.whiteColor()
       // hegeImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

Comment: Can you add any screenshot of your result?

Comment: yes. I have a screenshot above

Comment: And what result you want? can you show?because what your are trying for background color will not work.

Comment: yes I edit it again!

Comment: actually @DharmeshKheni -- answer is correct , in your side bar width is small thats y it cover it half , so in here use two views and one view for background for cover over all view controller and another one view for load your table items just like now

Comment: I think your hedgehog picture has own white background color, so it's not a UIImageView's problem. make your image's background transparent or do as @DharmeshKheni's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is you can add one more view above all and set that view color to `grayColor` and hide it at start and set its `alpha` to 0.8 and when sidebar appears show that view and when side bar hide you can hide that view.

Here is simple example code for you:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, sideBarDelegate {

    var sideBar : SideBar = SideBar()

    @IBOutlet weak var TransperentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TransperentView.hidden = true
        TransperentView.alpha = 0.8
        TransperentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuIteams: ["FirstIteam","SecondIteam","ThirdIteam","FourthIteam"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
    }

    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {

        sideBar.showSideBar(false)
        TransperentView.hidden = true  //hide view
    }
    @IBAction func index(sender: AnyObject) {

        TransperentView.hidden = false
        sideBar.showSideBar(true)   //show view

    }
}
```

Result will be:

[image]

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00889573171375815464) is sample project for more Info.

Comment: func sideBarWillOpen() {

        hideView.hidden = false
        hideView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        hideView.alpha = 0.5
    }
    
    func sideBarWillClose() {
        hideView.hidden = true
    }  I add another view and it works thanks:D!!

Comment: Happy to help you..:)